# "You can’t open the application “Terminal” because it is not supported on this type of Mac."

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-yosemite

Above is my latest gripe with OSX 10.10. It just started today. I've already restarted and still cannot get past this. Has anyone experienced this or does anyone know how to solve it?

This is what it looks like on my dock ->
[image: This is on my dock]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps Super User or Server Fault would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that's not an older version of Terminal? Have you tried running it from the Utilities folder?

To see where the targets are for the items in your dock, hold command while clicking them.